# Looking to find the slope of some values in a dataframe based on some conditions in other columns

Tags: r

I have some data from a mass spectrometer. I want to find the slope of some values based on the contents of other columns.

The data looks like this:

```
Protein | Channel | Ratio
A       | 127N    | 0.5
A       | 128N    | 0.7
A       | 127C    | 0.9
A       | 128C    | 0.4
B       | 127N    | 0.2
B       | 128N    | 0.5
B       | 127C    | 0.7
B       | 128C    | 0.3
```

I want to find 2 slopes of the "Ratio" values for each Protein, A and B. (In reality, this is for every unique df$Protein value in the entire dataframe).

The first value I want to find is the slope between Ratios from data from Channels 127N and 128N.

The second value I want to find is the slope between Ratios from data from Channels 127C and 128C.

N and C are two different experimental conditions. I think I'd have to make some sort of group first so that only Ns are put with Ns and Cs are put with Cs.

Any idea how to do this?

I would end up with data like this:

```
Protein | Condition | Slope
A       | N         | 0.2
A       | C         | -0.5
B       | N         | 0.3
B       | C         | -0.4
```

With 2 slopes for each protein, 1 per condition. Also, the order of the channels always has to be the same. I can change the Channel names to 1, 2, 3, 4 if that helps make it easier to make a slope.

Comment: If your data is sorted appropriately, you can do `df$Condition <- sub("\\d+", "", df$Channel);  aggregate(Ratio ~ Protein + Condition, df, diff)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you mean by sorted appropriately?

Comment: For the first value, using ratios 0.5 (from 127C) and 0.7 (from 128C) how do you calculate the "slope of ratios" to get 0.2?

Comment: Just because it's +0.2 over a 1 data point "difference." In reality, each channel represents a different time point - in this case, the 127s are 0h and the 128s are 24h. But there are 4 time points total per condition in the actual dataframe and all time points are 24h apart, so I can just use 1, 2, 3, 4 as the "time points" instead, since I'm interested in the relative differences in slopes for each Protein rather than the absolute values of the slopes. Eg here I'd want to know if there is a significant difference between the N and C conditions for protein A.

Comment: @RyanH. ultimately I'd want to take the whole data frame and identifiy the proteins that show significant differences in their slopes between N and C.

Comment: `diff()` returns the successive lagged differences of a vector so the order of the data matters.  In the case of a Protein x Condition combination of two values if the data was not in the desired order you'd get the inverse result.

Comment: @H1 ... please add your base solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using some `dplyr` functions

```r
df <- data.frame(Protein=as.character(c("A","A","A","A")),
                 Channel=as.character(c("127N", "128N", "127C", "128C")),
                 Ratio=as.numeric(c(0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 0.4)),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr)

# Create condition column
df$Condition <- substr(df$Channel, 4, 4)

df %>% 
  select(Protein, Condition, Ratio) %>% 
  group_by(Protein, Condition) %>% 
  mutate(Slope = Ratio - lag(Ratio, default = first(Ratio))) %>% # This produces the Slope
  mutate(Slope = round(Slope,1)) %>% # This rounds to one decimal place - change if necessary
  select(Protein, Condition, Slope) %>% 
  { .[seq(2, nrow(.), 2), ] }# This selects every second row
```

The output looks like so

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   Protein, Condition [2]
  Protein Condition Slope
  <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
1 A       N           0.2
2 A       C          -0.5
etc
```

Comment: This looks like it's going to work with a little bit of tweaking. What do the 4s mean in the df$Condition variable? Thanks so much!

Comment: `substr()` extracts a portion of a string (a substring). In this case, it's extracting just the fourth character. But it could take from the 2nd to the 19th character of a string like so `substr(your_string, 2, 19)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using tidyverse for this

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Separate Channel and Condition

```
df$Condition <- str_sub(df$Channel, -1)
df$Channel <- str_sub(df$Channel, 1, -2)
```

Then

```
df %>%
  select(Protein, Channel, Condition, Ratio) %>%
  group_by(Protein, Condition) %>%
  arrange(Protein, desc(Condition), Channel) %>%

  # For each row, subtract the previous value
  # This will produce NA for the first row of each group
  mutate(Slope = round(Ratio - lag(Ratio), 1)) %>%

  # Remove the rows with NA
  drop_na() %>%

  # Select just the desired columns
  select(Protein, Condition, Slope)
```

I added an extra data point (A, 129N, 0.9) so that one group had 3 time points to ensure that it works for more than 2 time points.

Results:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   Protein, Condition [4]
  Protein Condition  Slope
  <fct>   <chr>     <dbl>
1 A       N           0.2
2 A       N           0.2
3 A       C          -0.5
4 B       N           0.3
5 B       C          -0.4
```